# Facebook Request for App Review. Does it refer to native phone apps only?

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I received at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ the following message:

> Request for App Review
>   Your app was proactively submitted. As a result, permissions you once had access to now appear in your app dashboard as needing App Review. If you still need these permissions, resubmit for App Review. If you no longer need these permissions no action is required. Just wait 30-days from receipt of this notification and they will be removed from your request.
>   Status:
>   Status: Action required: Review and address feedback, and resubmit

See the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Someone told me: "Be careful. Facebook terminology calls everything an app, including an html web service. They may be referring to our web interface."

I was assuming that this Facebook Review exclusively referred to Apps, meaning Android apps or iOS apps, not including web services. I was more thinking about the Facebook Reviews for publishing to the Google Play Store. Do you know what they refer to? Thank you.

Comment: App includes web also. If you are using the API then you are using an app.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much. I had started to suspect that because from my website, I make requests to https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[My cliente ID], and I noticed that the client ID that I use for the website, I also use it for the Android app. Please write your comment as an answer so that I can accept it as a best answer and have this question marked as solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not. It refers to both native phone apps and web applications.